# Insert and update based on comparison of fields between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, dml

I would like to Insert a record in a table `if` a variable is not equal the same column in another table. Something like:

```
        Insert IGNORE INTO newtable
        SELECT * FROM oldtable
        WHERE url="www.theurl.com/1" AND 
              (field CoolThing from newtable != CoolThing from oldtable)
```

So `CoolThing` is a field (column).

Comment: What is `newtable`?  You did not use `ThingName` in your query. Use `!=` or `<>` for [not-equal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal).

Comment: @PM77-1 Sorry was a typo... See the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Insert IGNORE INTO newdata 
    SELECT o.* /* this is allowed only if the count and order of the
 columns  of the two tables are exactly the same */
   FROM olddata o left join 
    newdata n on n.coolthing=o.coolthing
    WHERE o.url="www.theurl.com/1" AND o.coolthing is NULL
```

Comment: That does not work... I basically want to check if a column have the same values in both tables, then do not insert, else insert.